# Properties of characters of representations

Tags: group-theory, summation, representation-theory, orthogonality, characters

Suppose $\chi$ is the character of the representation $\sigma:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ (where $G$ could be assumed to be the symmetric group as well), then do we know anything about the following sum
$$\sum_{\sigma}\sum_{x,y \in G} \chi_\sigma(x)^*\chi_\sigma(y)$$ where the outer sum over $\sigma$ runs over all possible irreducible representations of $G$.

Comment: Do you mean the irreducible representations of $G$? If you really mean all representations, there are infinitely many of them, so you'd have to specify some order to make the infinite sum well-defined.

Comment: Oops, you are right! Fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\chi_\sigma^*=\overline{\chi_\sigma}$. Recall the orthogonality of columns in the character table of $G$:
$$
\sum_{\sigma}\overline{\chi_\sigma}(g_i)\chi_\sigma(g_j)=|Z_G(g_i)|\delta_{ij},
$$
where the set $\{g_i\}$ is a set of representatives for the conjugacy classes in $G$ and $Z_G(g_i)$ is the centralizer of $g_i$. Suppose there are $r$ conjugacy classes, hence $r$ irreducible representations up to isomorphism. Therefore your sum is 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^r\sum_{x,y\in G}\overline{\chi_{\sigma_k}(x)}\chi_{\sigma_k}(y)=
\sum_{k=1}^r\sum_{i,j=1}^r\frac{|G|}{|Z_G(g_i)||Z_G(g_j)|}\overline{\chi_{\sigma_k}(g_i)}\chi_{\sigma_k}(g_j)=
\sum_{i,j=1}^r\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{|G|}{|Z_G(g_i)||Z_G(g_j)|}\overline{\chi_{\sigma_k}(g_i)}\chi_{\sigma_k}(g_j).
$$
Now, by the orthogonality relation, the sum over $k$ is zero unless $i=j$, in which case it's equal to the size of the centralizer of $g_i$. Thus we have that your sum is equal to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^r\frac{|G|}{|Z_G(g_i)|^2}|Z_G(g_i)|=\sum_{i=1}^r\frac{|G|}{|Z_G(g_i)|}=|G|.
$$

Comment: I'm sorry, is there a typo, where is the $k$ dependence in the double sum? Is it over the $\sigma_k$?. Also I have one more question, suppose I cared about $\sum_{\sigma}\sum_{x,y,z,w}\chi_{\sigma}(x)^*\chi_{\sigma}(y)^*\chi_{\sigma}(z)\chi_{\sigma}(w)$, would the same analysis give me $|G|^2$? If you think so, I could work it out on my own, but if not, do let me know! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Hi, your are correct, the $\sigma$ are indexed by $k$. I have edited my answer to reflect this. I think it is easy to deduce that the second sum you mention is actually $|G|^3$ from the identity for your first sum.